# Constant Acceleration

Tags: calculus

A Train leaves station A, heading in the direction of station B, from rest with constant acceleration *0.2 m s−2* . At the same time, another train leaves station B, heading in the direction of station A, from rest with constant acceleration *0.16 m s−2* . The Distance Between the two stations is *8.2 km*. find the time they meet at.

If an external viewer (K) is in the same plane as collision watched the collision at Angle Alpha,and another general observer relative to the prependicular point of collision. form an equation on what Acceleration and time would be invovling the factor of Alpha.[image]

I have edited this page, what I mean is that as a general observer, calculating the time of collision is easy but at a observer in the same plane as the collision watches the collision with the changing angle theta till the point of collision at angle alpha, how can you accurately calculate the effect of the angles on acceleration and time.

Comment: @m-stgt Otherwise the lengths of the trains may also have to be accounted for. That's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: In classical mechanics, you can use the Galilean transform to transform between any inertial observer, but the answers you get will always be consistent

Comment: You drew $\alpha$ wrong, as the statement says it is measured from the perpendicular.

Comment: @John Alexiou ,sorry about that mistake

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two trains are moving along the straight line joining stations A and B, and that they meet after $t$ seconds from the start time, we have $^{[1]}$

$$\frac{1}{2} (0.2 + 0.16) t^2 = 8200$$

Solving this equation for a positive real solution, would give us the time they meet at. It doesn't matter whose perspective you take. (We are not talking about theory of relativity, right?)

Also the displacement for B would be $-(8.2 \text{ km} - x)$. It's in the direction opposite to the displacement of A.

---

$^{[1]}$ Using

$$s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$

Initial velecity, $u$, is zero for both A and B.

Comment: _"We are not talking about theory of relativity, right?"_ Well, we are, since the trains move in opposite direction you have to add the abs value of accelerations, otherwise you have to subtract it and the trains would meet somwhere past B, not between A and B. Velocity and acceleration are vectors (in contrast to time which is a scalar).

Comment: Thank you sir, but I cannot vote up your answer since I only have two reputations

Comment: @m-stgt Perhaps there's a miscommunication. I was not talking about relative velocity or acceleration (which I did take into account) but Einstein's theory of relativity.

Comment: @MarxCarton No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: @Haris -- I know, I intentionally misunderstood it. Just because here the _relation_ of the movement, parallel or antiparallel, makes a big difference, where the two trains will meet and at which _relative_ velocity. Thus the sign of the accelearions should be explained and why they may be simply added. For the sake of it, me think.

Comment: Hi guys I changed the Question a Little bit who can help me understand how to work with this?